# Automount samba folder on Mac

Tags: macos, unix, admin, osx-mountain-lion, samba

I trying to make mount smb folder on startup.

I do like here - http://aj.tarachanowicz.com/?p=158

But I have error constantly - "Too many user".

May be somebody meet this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

My answer is an adaptation of the answer in https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3221944?start=15&tstart=0

The variation is, I moved the mount point from your home directory to a system area (e.g. /smb) and ensuring that the user can create that mount point, i.e. 4755 permissions.

1. Add this line to the end of `/etc/auto_master`:

   ```
   /-     auto_smb
   ```
2. Create parent folder:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /smb
   sudo chmod 4755 /smb
   ```
3. Create `/etc/auto_smb` with:

   ```
   /smb/folder -fstype=smbfs,soft ://domain;user:password@server/folder
   ```
4. Run automount:

   automount -vc

The troubleshooting points are:

1. If you encounter "Too many users" you need to review your SMB path for typos and syntax errors.
2. Also be careful of incorrect username / passwords, or passwords with special symbols. e.g. `@` would need to be replaced with `%40`.

Comment: "Too many users" was due to an incorrect server address for me... That was explicit...